# Laravel 5.4 call a model function on an instance returned by another laravel model function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables and the corresponding models which are connected as shown below:

**Telephones.php:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Telephones extends Model {
    protected $table = 'telephones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'telephone_id';
    public function UserTelephone() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users','user_id','user_id');
    }
}
```

**Addresses.php:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Addresses extends Model {
    protected $table = 'addresses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'address_id';
    public function UserAddress() {
        return $this ->hasOne('App\Models\Users','address_id','address_id');
    }
}
```

**Users.php:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Users extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

 }
```

In my view I want to connect user's telephone with user's address so I do the following:

```
<?php  $user_telephone = $telephone->UserTelephone()->first();
       $address = $user_telephone->UserAddress()->first();
?>
```

but it fails with error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line xxxx:
Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::UserAddress()
```

Any ideas how I could solve it?

Comment: There's a space that isn't supposed to be there. Change `return $this ->hasOne('App\Models\Users','address_id','address_id');` to `return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users','address_id','address_id');`

Comment: It was a typo when I wrote the question here, in my code there isn't this space but code still not working.

Comment: Can you share your table structures?

Comment: **addresses table**
`address_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address_city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`address_street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`address_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL

**users table**
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL

**telephones table:**    
    `telephone_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    `shop_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,    
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your model functions like this :

```
    $user_telephone = $telephone->UserTelephone; 
    $address = $user_telephone->UserAddress;
```

this will be okay only if $telephone its a Telephone model

EDIT

Your error is in the place you declare you model relationship
change this:

```
 return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users','user_id','user_id');
```

to this

```
 return $this->hasOne(Users::class,'user_id','user_id');
```

and the same with your other function

*make sure what is your models name.. most of the times is `User`

Comment: My model's name is Users. I have tried the suggested corrections, error was fixed but `$address` variable is empty. However, there is a record in the address table that matches the criteria.

Comment: Just try your relationship in your controller to see if it works or if it returns any data. @KoKa

Answer (score 0):

On your telephones and address model, I would say to use Belongs to instead of Has One.

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Users;

class Addresses extends Model {
    protected $table = 'addresses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'address_id';
    public function UserAddress() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
    }
}

class Telephones extends Model {
    protected $table = 'telephones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'telephone_id';
    public function UserTelephone() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
    }
}
```

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one
Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship

The reason your case doesn't work on user address is because you may not have the address_id field on your user model.

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users','id','user_id');
```

You are creating a relationship so therefore you need to let it know how they're connected. I would suggest read more about relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I corrected the code and used `belongsTo` instead of `hasOne` and I have `address_id` field on my **Users model**.  As commented above, I managed to fixed the error using  `$user_telephone = $telephone->UserTelephone; ` and `$address = $user_telephone->UserAddress;` but $`address` is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Telephone Model :

```
   public function UserTelephone() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users','user_id','user_id');
    }
```

Address Model :

```
    public function UserAddress() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users','address_id','address_id');
    }
```

Controller :

```
 $telephone =Telephone::find(1);  //get first telephone
 $user_telephone = $telephone->UserTelephone; // get User 
 $address = $user_telephoneObject->UserAddress; //get Address Of the user
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions but code still fails with the same error.

Comment: I have tried your proposal after editing your code and the result is the following: error is fixed, `$user_telephone` has entries but `$address` variable is empty. However, as mention in my comment below Onix suggestion, there is a record in the address table that matches the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve it, the issue was that I was trying to call a model's function on the wrong object.
My goal was to get the address when user was known. To be more specific I had the following relationship: telephone->user->address. As you could see to the initial posted code, I declared 2 functions, `UserTelephone` and `UserAddress`. Then I called `UserTelephone` on a `telephone object` and `UserAddress` on a `recipient object`. This was the reason that my code failed. Had to create a new function on `Users` model to be able to get the address when user was know. Working code posted below:

**Telephones.php:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Telephones extends Model {
    protected $table = 'telephones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'telephone_id';
    public function UserTelephone() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users','user_id','user_id');
    }
}
```

**Addresses.php:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Addresses extends Model {
    protected $table = 'addresses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'address_id';
    public function UserAddress() {
        return $this ->belongsTo('App\Models\Users','address_id','address_id');
    }
}
```

**Users.php:**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Users extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    public function Address() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Addresses','address_id','address_id');
    }
}
```

In my view:

```
<?php  $address = $telephone->UserTelephone->Address()->first();?>
```